# Laravel Blade change row color when variable value is different in loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a report page that loops through a collection and displays the data in a generic bootstrap template table - it's showing data about users, and one user can have multiple rows in the table. I group the rows by the user ID and I want to basically stripe the table rows based on the user ID (not just alternating rows). So, for example, I might display 4 rows for user ID = 5 with a white background and then 2 rows for user ID = 6 with a gray background.  I'd just use a local variable in straight php, but is there an elegant/clean way to do this in the blade templates?

```
@foreach($payments->getDetails() AS $k=>$detail)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $detail->payment->userid }}</td>
    <td>${{ $detail->payment->amount }}</td>
    <td>{{ $detail->payment->status }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

In this example, $payments is a collection of $paymentsDetails objects. So based on the $detail->payment->userid value I'd like to determine the  class or background color.

Thank you for any help in this.

Comment: You could add a column in the user table to assign each user a unique color code and call it in the loop, just make sure you tie add a belongsTo relationship on the payment model to access the user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this via www.laracasts.com from user @Cronix:

> I'd do it the way you were thinking originally and just use
>   @php/@endphp blade directives to determine if the userid has changed
>   during each loop iteration and if it does change the color.
>
> ```
> @php 
> $lastid = null;
> $rowclass = 'grey';
> @endphp
>
> @foreach($payments->getDetails() AS $k=>$detail)
> @php 
>  //if userid changed from last iteration, store new userid and change color
>  if ($lastid !== $detail->payment->userid)
>  {
>     $lastid = $detail->payment->userid;
>     if ($rowclass == 'grey') $rowclass = 'white';
>     else $rowclass = 'grey';
>  }
> @endphp
> <tr class="{{ $rowclass }}">
>     <td>{{ $detail->payment->userid }}</td>
>     <td>${{ $detail->payment->amount }}</td>
>     <td>{{ $detail->payment->status }}</td>
> </tr>
> @endforeach
> ```

If anyone out there has a more elegant Blade-focused idea on how to solve it, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... This assumes the rows are ordered by user id naturally (it would not work otherwise in your example anyway...)... So here's the thought...

If the user id is odd, then give it a color, if it is even, give it the alternate color... that would work... Sort of ...

```
@foreach($payments->getDetails() AS $k=>$detail)
<tr>
    <td class="{{$detail->payment->userid % 2 == 0 ? 'evenColor':'oddColor'">{{ $detail->payment->userid }}</td>
    <td class="{{$detail->payment->userid % 2 == 0 ? 'evenColor':'oddColor'">{{ $detail->payment->amount }}</td>
    <td class="{{$detail->payment->userid % 2 == 0 ? 'evenColor':'oddColor'">{{ $detail->payment->status }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Something like this would also work... not sure I like it though

```
@foreach($payments->getDetails() AS $k=>$detail)
    @if($detail->payment->userid % 2 == 0)
        <tr>
            <td class="evencolor">{{ $detail->payment->userid }}</td>
            <td class="evencolor">>${{ $detail->payment->amount }}</td>
            <td class="evencolor">{{ $detail->payment->status }}</td>
        </tr>
    @else
        <tr>
            <td class="oddcolor">{{ $detail->payment->userid }}</td>
            <td class="oddcolor">${{ $detail->payment->amount }}</td>
            <td class="oddcolor">{{ $detail->payment->status }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Anyway... just a possible direction... someone else might have a more elegant idea...

Comment: hey @Serge - the issue is that it could be a randomized list of user IDs, so you could have a number of odds or evens in a row, so this solution wouldn't help.

Comment: If users are in random order why bother with this then... ? You will end up with a random bunch of coloured lines...

Comment: There will be multiple records for a single user, and the records will be grouped by user id, but sorted by another value, so for ease-of-reading I want to stripe it by user id, but I can't guarantee the order of user id.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys the methods above failed for me, incase anyone els needs this : im using laravel 5.4 with php 5.6===> this is what has worked for me;

```
@php

                if ( $post->dbdata == 'approved'):
                    $color = 'green';
                elseif ( $post->dbdata == 'Pending'):
                $color = 'yellow';
                elseif ( $post->dbdata == 'rejected'):
                $color = 'red';
                else:
                $color = 'black';
                endif;

                @endphp
                <tr style="background-color: {{$color}}">
                    <td>
                        <h6>{{ $post->dbdata }}</h6>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```